# Which are the best extensions for use Facebook and stop the cookies and tracking?

Tags: firefox, cookies, tracking

I ´m trying with **Ad Block Plus, Ghostery, Disconect and Self-Destruct Cookies** in Firefox.
Can you recommend some tips to stop the tracking?

Answer (score 0):

The "Do Not Track" feature in Firefox is useful for telling sites that you do not want to be tracked. A detailed guide on enabling this feature is available on Firefox's support page : http://mzl.la/WL6fUP .

Besides, if you want an extra level of security, I would suggest you to use the "NoScript" browser extension(https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/). NoScript blocks JavaScript and other executable content on website thus effectively protecting you from tracking codes on websites.

And if you want real privacy use a proxy or VPN. Another good idea is to use the tor browser ( torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en).